# "Deploy from Manifest" then "install the Addon" for my account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

Objective: "Deploy from Manifest" then "install the addon" for my account, so When I open a sheet a simple menu appears in sheet Addon menu.

I looking around literally hours to figure out this one. This is simple menu creation for sheet:

```
function onOpen(e) {
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu(); // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
 menu.addItem('Start workflow', 'startWorkflow');
 menu.addToUi();
}
```

I can't figure out how the appsscript.json should be so when I "Deploy from Manifest" and install works on all my sheets including new sheets.
More info: The script is standalone without container.

I also doesn't have gsuite when I publish the Addon I just have "External" option and the addon goes under "Review".

So I Think "Deploy from Manifest" is my option but I can't undrestand how, I appreciate if you correct this for me or tell me how I can achieve my goal.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
  "runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Archiver",
      "logoUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Q3Yr2wSiE4s_7toyqf8XZvcdtgiyWkYF",
      "useLocaleFromApp": true,
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onOpen",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "universalActions": [{
        "label": "Learn more about Cats",
        "openLink": "https://cats.com"
      }]
    },
     "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onOpen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my current Deploy from manifest look like:

[image]

This is how my sheet look like:

[image]

This is how I want to look like for all my sheets including future creations:

[image]

Comment: Do you have this [side icon panel](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/starting-addons#starting_a_add-on)?

Comment: If I add "Gmail" or "Calendar" or "Drive" in manifest, I can have that in those apps, but not for sheet or slide. I was looking for that also which why I can't get it in my sheet or slide and in some point I give up and I just need a simple menu. However if you can tell me how I can have that in my sheet also will be helpful. Here is the Link: function is not running or I can't see that icon in right side : https://gist.github.com/mhndlsz/8b4bcb55a5e4c95f8bfd2e004f52779b

Comment: If you just need that addon menu, you need to publish the addon and go through the review process. This Google workspace addon is pretty new and not much is known about how to make it appear in sheets.

Comment: What about the other one? side icon in sheet.

Comment: Do you have a side icon in your sheet?

Comment: I don't have as I explained above in comments. Not on the sheet nor in slides. This us the manifest for slide, but the side panel icon doesn't show, it just shows in Gmail, Calendar and Drive. gist.github.com/mhndlsz/8b4bcb55a5e4c95f8bfd2e004f52779b

Comment: I think Side icon is the only way to access "Google workspace addon" AFAICT. "Editor addon", on the other hand add menus. Until recently, "Workspace add on" was never supported in sheets or any of the other editors.

Comment: Infact, part of the documentation https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/gsuite-restrictions#_extend_all_g_suite_apps still states sheets isn't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is a bug

Apparently Google Workspace Add-ons don't work for Sheets, Docs and Slides despite the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/types) says they would.

I filed a report in Google Issuetracker so they will take a look at this. Feel free to star it as they prioritize responding to the issues with the most stars. Here is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170819044